# Accessing old values without :OLD and in a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, collation

As discussed [here](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/15682217), I'm unable to use :OLD and :NEW on columns with collation other than USING_NLS_COMP. I'm trying to find a way around this but haven't been successful so far.

What I can do is access the new rows by using a compound trigger, saving IDs of changed rows in AFTER EACH ROW and then looping over these and selecting rows in AFTER STATEMENT. The same doesn't apply for old values unfortunately.

Here is an example of what isn't working:

```sql
CREATE TABLE example_table (
  id VARCHAR2(10),
  name NVARCHAR2(100)
);
CREATE TABLE log_table (
  id VARCHAR2(10),
  new_name NVARCHAR2(100),
  old_name NVARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER example_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON example_table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  INSERT INTO log_table VALUES(:old.id, :new.name, :old.name);
END;

INSERT INTO example_table VALUES('01', 'Daniel');
-- this works as expected
UPDATE example_table SET name = ' John' WHERE id = '01';
SELECT * FROM log_table;

DROP TABLE example_table;

CREATE TABLE example_table (
  id VARCHAR2(10),
  -- this is the problematic part
  name NVARCHAR2(100) COLLATE XCZECH_PUNCTUATION_CI
);

INSERT INTO example_table VALUES('01', 'Daniel');
-- here nothing is inserted into log_example, if you try to
-- recompile the trigger you'll get error PLS-00049
UPDATE example_table SET name = ' John' WHERE id = '01';
SELECT * FROM log_table;

DROP TABLE example_table;
DROP TABLE log_table;
DROP TRIGGER example_trigger;
```

If somebody has a solution for this it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Did you recreate the trigger after you recreate the table? It doesn't appear so from your script, other than the comment about PLS-00049.